# Sharepoint - Can't Set Sealed Property to False

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to delete a sealed field from a Sharepoint 2010 Document Library. The field in question was originally the default Sharepoint Title field that has since been renamed. I'm in the Sharepoint Management Shell, but when I try to update the `Sealed` property to false, I get the following error message:

> Exception setting "Sealed": "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Note that I was able to successfully unseal a different field in the same list using the same method.

Here's the full set of commands I'm using:

```
$web = Get-SPweb("myurl")
$list = $web.Lists["mylist"]
$field = $list.Fields["column to delete"]
$field.AllowDeletion = $true
$field.Sealed = $false -->Here's where I get the error
```

If I were able to updated the `Sealed` property, I'd continue with the following:

```
$field.Delete()
$list.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Are there any other properties that I need to change in order to update `Sealed`? Is the Title field uniquely protected?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet regarding the purpose of sealing:

Sometimes, you want to make absolutely sure that someone can’t go in and change your content type via the Windows SharePoint Services user interface. If an administrator were to delete or rename columns in your content type this can cause all sorts of issues as things may or may not be prorogated down to the child types. You might also want to ensure that a content type is only created / modified by using a feature and CAML. To solve this, a content type can be marked as sealed and it can only be marked as sealed through the object model. This prevents any casual changes to the content type via the user interface.

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/03/11/how-to-seal-a-content-type.aspx

[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.contains.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I solve such kind of problems with this code (we update field's xml schema directly):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://my-web-url
$list = $web.Lists["myList"]
$field = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("myField")
$fxml = [xml]$field.SchemaXml
$fxml.Field.Sealed = "FALSE"
$field.SchemaXml = $fxml.InnerXml
$field.Update();
$web = Get-SPWeb http://my-web-url
$list = $web.Lists["myList"]
$field = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("myField")
$field.Sealed = $false;
$field.Update();
```

Maybe in your case you should update web field too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this with this approach:

1. Disable content types.
2. Update the Sealed property via powershell.
3. Enable content types.

Answer (score -2):

This script can help you to change a field in a sealed content type:

```
param([string]$webUrl="http://spdev", [string]$contentTypeName="myContenttype", [string]$fieldName="myTitle", [boolean]$required=$true)
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
clear
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$ct = $web.ContentTypes[$contentTypeName];
$oldSealedValue = $ct.Sealed;
Write-Host "content type Sealed Property $($ct.Sealed)"
if($ct.Sealed)
{
    $ct.Sealed = $false;
}
$field = $ct.FieldLinks[$fieldName];
$field.Required = $required;
Write-Host "set field $($fieldName) Required $($ct.Required)"
　
if($oldSealedValue)
{
    $ct.Sealed = $true;
}
$ct.Update($true);
$web.Update();
$web.Dispose();
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21497240)